# REVOKE privileges in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

Can anyone please let me know how to revoke the delete privilege from SYS.AUD$ table? I tried with the below query REVOKE DELETE ON SYS.AUD$ FROM Schema_name; but got below error..SQL Error: ORA-01927: cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant
01927. 00000 -  "cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant"
*Cause:    You can only revoke privileges you granted.
*Action:   Don't revoke these privileges.

I have given GRANT ALL Privileges to that user, but still getting the same error

Comment: For a start: When saying "I have given GRANT ALL Privileges to that user" - are you talking about the user who tries to execute the `REVOKE`? (The error message does suggest, the user trying the `REVOKE`, lacks the right to do so.)

Comment: Tried with SYS login the issue got resolved

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Turning a comment into an answer:</sub>

The error message is less about the user to be changed as the user trying to execute the change. In other words: Please use an appropriately privileged user to `REVOKE`.